# Getting xml data attribut with PHP

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I've this xml

```
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://aviationweather.gov/adds/schema/metar1_2.xsd">
<request_index>471527627</request_index>
<data_source name="metars"/>
<request type="retrieve"/>
<errors/>
<warnings/>
<time_taken_ms>20</time_taken_ms>
<data num_results="1">
<METAR>
<raw_text>
EDDF 121020Z 20011KT 9999 FEW032 BKN130 05/01 Q1013 R88/CLRD// NOSIG
</raw_text>
<station_id>EDDF</station_id>
<observation_time>2017-01-12T10:20:00Z</observation_time>
<latitude>50.05</latitude>
<longitude>8.6</longitude>
<temp_c>5.0</temp_c>
<dewpoint_c>1.0</dewpoint_c>
<wind_dir_degrees>200</wind_dir_degrees>
<wind_speed_kt>11</wind_speed_kt>
<visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
<altim_in_hg>29.911417</altim_in_hg>
<quality_control_flags>
<no_signal>TRUE</no_signal>
</quality_control_flags>
<sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="3200"/>
<sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="13000"/>
<flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
<metar_type>SPECI</metar_type>
<elevation_m>113.0</elevation_m>
</METAR>
</data>
</response>
```

At the bottom there are two lines with the same name:

```
<sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="3200"/>
<sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="13000"/>
```

---

How can I get with PHP the attributes of both names?
I will have an output like this:

*FEW 3200*

*BKN 13000*

Thank you very much!! Regards, Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$xml_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$sk_cond = $xml_obj->data->METAR->sky_condition;
foreach ($sk_cond as $cond) {
        echo $cond->attributes()->{'sky_cover'} . ' ' . $cond->attributes()->{'cloud_base_ft_agl'} . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to achieve it. It's a little verbose way to deal with XML, but is good to understand what you are doing.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$skyConds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('sky_condition');
foreach ($skyConds as $sk) {
    $skyCover = $sk->getAttribute('sky_cover');
    $cbfa = $sk->getAttribute('cloud_base_ft_agl');
    print_r ("FEW $skyCover $cbfa" . "\n");
}
```